# Android, receiving order of SCREEN_OFF, SCREEN_ON, USER_PRESENT

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a service that would take a rest when device is locked.

I found the the most compatible way is listening to the 3 intents:
USER_PRESENT, SCREEN_ON, SCREEN_OFF

But are there any guarantee on the receiving order of the 3 intents?
i.e. would they always be received in the following order:

- SCREEN_OFF
- SCREEN_ON
- USER_PRESENT

For example, if the user disabled lock screen in Settings, would SCREEN_ON still fired before USER_PRESENT unconditionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I've understood your requirements.

There is no reassurance that there is a particular order for every user. This is because some users will only employ settings that means that the device locked after a particular amount of time. Say device will only be locked if 15 minutes has elapsed since the last password was correctly entered. This means that screen on is not necessarily followed by user present.

However, the user present broadcast will not be sent unless the screen on broadcast was sent before it. Indeed screen off broadcast will precede screen on. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this not always is the case. Specifically, just recently I have been presented with a log of my app showing USER_PRESENT recorded just before the SCREEN_ON, again and again. This is on a fairly new Xiaomi device running Android 10.

Fingerprint authentication is used to Unlock. Can it have some impact?